# foreach finds only the last element of the array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get all values of my array but I only get the last element.

(last description and last link).

here is the code:

```
$content = str_get_html($html);
$links = $content->find('.myclass a');

foreach($links as $k => $v)
{
    $descr= $v-> plaintext;
    $link_to= $v->href;

    $a=array( 
            1 => $descr, 
            2 => $link_to);
}

return a$;
```

how can I loop the complete array?

Answer (score 5):

You are overwriting the same array every loop. You need to add another dimension:

```
$content = str_get_html($html);
$links = $content->find('.myclass a');

$a = array();
foreach($links as $k => $v) {
    $descr = $v->plaintext;
    $link_to = $v->href;

    $a[] = array(1 => $descr, 2 => $link_to);
    // ^ add another dimension

    // DONT USE THIS! You are overwriting it every loop
    // $a = array(1 => $descr, 2 => $link_to);
}

// return a$; ? a$ maybe `$a`
```